# Limpiar csv de celdas vacías en bash

Tags: linux, bash, csv

Tengo este código:

```
while read -r line;
do


printf '%s\n' $line | grep -E "(GP?|MS?),(F?|M?),(1[5-7]),(U?|R?),[a-zA-Z0-9]*,(A?|T?),[1-4],[0-4],[a-z_]*,[a-z]*,[a-z]*,[a-z]*,[1-4],[1-4],[0-4],(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),(yes?|no?),[1-5],[1-5],[3-5],[1-5],[3-5],[1-5],[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*,[0-9]*" | sort -n -t , -k 3 | sed '/,O,/d;s/GP/Gabriel Pereira/g;/,O,/d;s/MS/Mousinho da Silveira/g' | cut -d ',' -f 1,2,3,9,10,12,14,21,23,24,26,30,31,32,33 | paste -sd ',' >> students_apartado_b.csv

   
done < student-mat.csv
```

Que básicamente trata a un `.csv` aplicándole unos filtros, y crea un nuevo `.csv` con los nuevos datos que recoge. El problema es que me agrega muchas filas vacías.

Para eliminar estas celdas vacías he probado con lo siguiente, sin tener resultados:

```
grep "\S"

sed '/^$/d' 

grep -Ev "^$"
```

¿Como puedo eliminar las filas vacías que me devuelve ese filtrado para agregarlo al nuevo `.csv`?

Actualmente me devuelve esto:

```
School  Sex Age Mjob    Fjob    Guardian    Studytime   Higher  Romantic    Famrel  Goout   Absences    G1  G2  G3
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
Gabriel Pereira M   15  health  services    father  1   yes no  4   3   2   14  14  14  
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
Gabriel Pereira M   17  services    services    mother  1   yes no  5   5   16  6   5   5   
Gabriel Pereira M   16  health  other   father  1   yes no  3   3   4   8   10  10
```

Comment: ¿celdas vacías o líneas vacías? A todo esto, ¿por qué con While bash y no con Awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con sed:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' nombre_archivo.csv > nuevo_archivo.csv
```

Esa instrucción encuentra toda una linea que empieza con espacio, solo contiene espacio, y termina en espacio, o sea, una linea vacia, y la omite, claro. Luego con el operador `>` vuelcas el resultado en un archivo nuevo o sobreescribiéndolo.

Answer (score 0):

No te las vacía con el comando `sed '/^$/d'` porque son líneas en blanco, pero están con espacios.

Debería funcionarte con `sed '/^ *$/d'`

A ver si hay suerte